When Lavf58.20.100 encoder released?
Can anyone tell be Lavf58.20.100 encoder when has been released? I want to find video's creation date, but it is deleted from metadata.
Thanks, Csaba

According to FFmpeg's Git history, libavformat 58.20.100 came into existence in March 2022 and was released as part of FFmpeg 5.1 in July 2022. Because software is not always updated immediately (and especially not FFmpeg), the file could have been produced anywhere between Jul 2022 and Oct 2024.
Note that libavformat is not an encoder but a muxer – its only job is to assemble already encoded audio/video streams into e.g. an MP4 or MKV file (encoding is handled by libavcodec aka Lavc) – so this date only tells you when this particular file was produced, but not when the video stream was encoded. (Remuxing of video files is a common task, e.g. to change MKV to MP4 or to add/remove subtitle streams, and this could result in a new Lavf#.#.# label being added to old videos.)
Of course, even if it were a codec version, it still couldn't tell you whether this is the original video stream or whether it's a re-encode of an older video stream.

Thanks so much!
